# How can I add CSS or JavaScript files?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to include a CSS and a JavaScript file, without linking them to a theme in particular.

Sometimes, I create small sites without modifying the theme at all, but I still need some minor CSS/JavaScript changes that don't justify creating a sub-theme. I wouldn't mind creating two "quick" and "global" files directly on the Drupal directory just for that.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a module, give it a libraries file (MODULE.libraries.yml):

```
global:
  js:
    /js.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      /css.css: {}
```

In the .module file, implement [`hook_page_attachments`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.6.x):

```
function MODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MODULE/global';
}
```

When you enable the module (or clear cache if it's an existing module), the CSS and JS will be included on every page.